# find last 15 users that logged in - even if some of them already logged out

Tags: command-line, users

i need to find the last 15 users that logged in to the system.
i know there are commands like 'w' or 'who' or 'users' but as much as i know those commands refer only to users currnetly logged-in.
but i need the user names of the 15 last active users - even if they already logged out...

the man of users say:

> users - print the user names of users currently logged in to the current host

which command/s i need to find data about users that not active right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `last` command lists the last logged-in users.  The data comes from `/var/log/wtmp` and can be limited to n-lines with the `-n <number>` option.  Other options allow one to select records "since" or "until" particular login times.

If the `wtmp` file doesn't exist, no logging occurs.  To create the file if it doesn't exist, `touch` the file and set the ownership to "root:utmp" with 664 permissions.

Comment: Thank a lot JRFeguson, that exactly what i wanted.
The second part is irrelevent since i'm not the system admin, but this is good thing to know anyway.